# Calculation logic formula models with prolog

Tags: prolog

Given a CNF logic formula 
`[[a, b, c], [b, d], [not(d), a]]` that is equal to `((a or b or c) and (b or d) and (not d or a))`, how do I calculate its models (possible values for its atoms that makes the formula `true`), using prolog? This is what i've got so far:

A valuation to the formula is a list of terms in the form os `val(X,B)`, where `X` is an atom, and `B` is its value (0 or 1).

The relation `value(X, Vs, B)` is given by

```
value(X, [val(X, B)|_], B) :− !.
value(X, [_|Ps], B) :− value(X, Ps, B).
```

and its true whenever `B` is the value for the atom `X` in the valuation `Vs`.

The relation `sp(F, Ss)`, given by

```
sp([],[]).
sp([F|Fs], Ss) :- setof(A, member(A,F), R), sp(Fs, N), append(R,N,M), setof(B,member(B,M),Ss).
```

and its true whenever `Ss` is the list of atoms in logic formula F.

The relation `valuation(As, Vs)`, given by

```
valuation([],[]).
valuation([A|As], [V|Vs]) :- (V = val(A,0); V = val(A,1)), valuation(As,Vs).
```

that is true whenever `Vs` is a possible valuation for the list of atoms `As`.

---

**What I need**:

The relation `ext(F, Vs, B)` that is true whenever `F` is a formula, `Vs` is a possible valuation for that formula, and `B` is the value of the formula applying `Vs` valuation. For example, the consult

```
ext([[a], [not(b), c]] , [val(a, 1), val(b, 0), val(c , 1)], B).
```

should return the value B = 1.

The relation `model(F,Vs)` that is true whenever the valuation `Vs` is a model for the formula `F`.

The relation `models(F, Ms)` that is true whenever `Ms` is a list which elements are models for the formula F. I guess we need to use prolog’s `setof` here.

And, at last, I don't know whats the best implementation of `val(X,B)` to make it work. I dont know if I should specify `val(_,1)` and `val(_,0)` to be true or only `val(_,1)`, what is better knowing the other relations to be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally finish it while waiting for replies, and improved it using max66's answer.

I made it to accept propositional logic forms too, so `models/2` accepts both styles (CNF and Propositional form, based on operators `and`, `not`, `or`, `imp`, `iff` that I set).

```
:- op(400, fy , not).
:- op(500, xfy, and).
:- op(600, xfy, or ).
:- op(700, xfy, imp).
:- op(800, xfy, iff ).

distr(_, [], []).
distr([], _, []).
distr([C|Cs], Ds, Es) :- distr_un(C, Ds, Ss), distr(Cs, Ds, Ts), append(Ss, Ts, Es).
distr_un(_, [], []).
distr_un(C, [D|Ds], [E|Es]) :- append(C, D, E), distr_un(C, Ds, Es).

cnf(F, [[F]]) :- atom(F), !.
cnf(not(F), [[not(F )]]) :- atom(F), !.
cnf(not not F, Rs) :- cnf(F, Rs).
cnf(not (F imp G), Rs) :- cnf(F and not G, Rs).
cnf(not (F iff G), Rs) :- cnf((F and not G) or (not F and G), Rs).
cnf(not(F and G), Rs) :- cnf((not F) or (not G), Rs).
cnf(not(F or G), Rs) :- cnf((not F) and (not G), Rs).
cnf(F and G, Rs) :- cnf(F, Cs), cnf(G, Ds), append(Cs, Ds, Rs).
cnf(F or G, Rs) :- cnf(F, Cs), cnf(G, Ds), distr(Cs, Ds, Rs).
cnf(F imp G, Rs) :- cnf((not F) or G, Rs).
cnf(F iff G, Rs) :- cnf((not F or G) and (not G or F), Rs).

val(X,0) :- atom(X).
val(X,1) :- atom(X).
value(X, [val(X, B)|_], B) :- !.
value(X, [_|Ps], B) :- value(X, Ps, B), !.
value(not X, [val(X, B)|_], V) :- V is 1-B, !.
value(not X, [_|Ps], B) :- value(not X, Ps, B), !.
sp([],[]).
sp([F|Fs], Ss) :- setof(A1, member(not A1, F), R1), setof(A, (member(A,F), atom(A)), R),  sp(Fs, N), append(R,N,M1), append(M1, R1, M), setof(B,member(B,M),Ss), !.
sp([F|Fs], Ss) :- setof(A, (member(A,F), atom(A)), R),  sp(Fs, N), append(R,N,M), setof(B,member(B,M),Ss), !.
sp([F|Fs], Ss) :- setof(A, (member(not A,F), atom(A)), R),  sp(Fs, N), append(R,N,M), setof(B,member(B,M),Ss), !.
valuation([],[]).
valuation([A|As], [V|Vs]) :- (V = val(A,0); V = val(A,1)), valuation(As,Vs).
ext([F|Fs], Vs, B) :- sp([F|Fs], Ss), valuation(Ss, Vs), ext_([F|Fs], Vs, B).
ext_([], _, 1).
ext_([F|Fs], Vs, 1) :- cl(F, Vs, 1), ext_(Fs, Vs, 1).
ext_([F|Fs], Vs, 0) :- cl(F, Vs, 0); ext_(Fs, Vs, 0).
cl([A|As], Vs, 1) :- value(A,Vs,1); cl(As, Vs, 1).
cl([A|As], Vs, 0) :- value(A,Vs,0), cl(As,Vs,0).
cl([], _, 0).
model(F, Vs) :- ext(F, Vs, 1).
models(F, Vs) :- cnf(F, Fs), setof(V, model(Fs, V), Vs).
models(F, Vs) :- setof(V, model(F, V), Vs).
```

I tested it and it seems to be working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand exactly what you want but...

First of all, let me try to simplify your code.

1) I think your `value/2` should be written as

```
value(X, [val(X, B) | _], B).

value(X, [_ | Ps], B) :-
   value(X, Ps, B).
```

2) I don't understand the purpose of your `sp/2` but seems to me that can be simplified as

```
sp([], []).

sp([[A] | Fs], [A | Ss]) :-
  sp(Fs, Ss).

sp([[A | As] | Fs], [A | Ss]) :- 
  append(As, Fs, N),
  sp(N, Ss).
```

3) I don't understand the purpose of your `valutation/2` but seems to me that can be simplified as

```
isBool(0).

isBool(1).

valuation([], []).

valuation([A | As], [val(A, B) | Vs]) :-
  isBool(B),
  valuation(As,Vs).
```

Now I try to respond to your question

4)

> I need [...] The relation `ext(F, Vs, B)` that is true whenever `F`
>   is a formula, `Vs` is a possible valuation for that formula, and `B`
>   is the value of the formula applying `Vs` valuation

I suppose the following should work [caution: not tested really much]

```
ext([], _, 1).

ext([[] |_], _, 0).

ext([[X | L1] | L2], Vs, B) :-
  value(X, Vs, 0),
  ext([L1 | L2], Vs, B).

ext([[not(X) | L1] | L2], Vs, B) :-
  value(X, Vs, 1),
  ext([L1 | L2], Vs, B).

ext([[X | _] | L], Vs, B) :-
  value(X, Vs, 1),
  ext(L, Vs, B).

ext([[not(X) | _] | L], Vs, B) :-
  value(X, Vs, 0),
  ext(L, Vs, B).
```

5)

> I need [...] The relation `model(F,Vs)` that is true whenever the
>   valuation `Vs` is a model for the formula `F`

What about the following ?

```
model(F, Vs) :-
  ext(F, Vs, _).  % or ext(F, Vs, 1)?
```

6)

> I need [...] The relation models(F, Ms) that is true whenever Ms is a
>   list which elements are models for the formula F

If I understand correctly what do you want, given `model/2`, `models/2` could be written as

```
models(_, []).

models(F, [Vs | Vl]) :-
  model(F, Vs),
  models(F, Vl).
```

7)

> I don't know whats the best implementation of val(X,B) to make it
>   work. I dont know if I should specify val(*,1) and val(*,0) to be true
>   or only val(_,1)

Not sure to understand your question.

`val/2` can't be true for every value; so you can't impose true `val(_,1)` and/or `val(_,0)` because given an atom (`a`, by example) is true `val(a,1)` *or* `val(a,0)` but ins't true `val(X,1)` for every `X`.

Comment: On item 2, that was the first form of my `sp` relation but in that way we don't get a list with unique items (if the formula is `[[a,b],[a,c]]` we would get a list `[a,b,a,c]`. I needed a list with unique items like `[a,b,c]`. That's why I wrote it that way.

on 5) you are right, its `model(F, Vs) :- ext(F, Vs, 1).`

on 6) its pretty much like that but I need a list of unique items, so I guess I'll use 'setof'

Answer (score 0):

Another approach here. Translate to executable Prolog, and reify a specific execution (i.e. a proof with specific symbol bindings):

```
ext(F, Vs, B) :-
    or_list(F, [], C, Vs), !,
    assign(Vs), ( call(C), B = true ; B = false ).

assign(Dict) :- maplist(domain, Dict).

domain(val(_, true)).
domain(val(_, false)).

or_list([A], D, T, Du) :-
    !, and_list(A, D, T, Du).
or_list([A|As], D, ( T ; Ts ), Du) :-
    and_list(A, D, T, Dut),
    or_list(As, Dut, Ts, Du).

and_list([V], D, T, Du) :-
    !, negation(V, D, T, Du).
and_list([V|Vs], D, ( T , Ts ), Du) :-
    negation(V, D, T, Dut),
    and_list(Vs, Dut, Ts, Du).

negation(not(V), D, \+T, Du) :-
    !, sym_bind(V, D, T, Du).
negation(V, D, T, Du) :-
    sym_bind(V, D, T, Du).

sym_bind(V, D, T, D) :-
    memberchk(val(V, T), D), !.
sym_bind(V, D, T, [val(V, T)|D]).
```

note:

- false/true instead of 0/1
- list to structure translation: could be way shorter, using foldl or DCGs or passing down the operators (that is (;)/2 (,)/2 (+)/1), but this way the Prolog patterns should be clearer...